# API is failing in postman but works fine in browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am trying to fetch the list of items using /_api/lists. From browser its working fine. But when tried in postman, it's returning 401 unauthorised. I have even added the NTLM authorization header which I got from the browser.

What could be the issue?

TIA

Comment: Have you seen this? https://medium.com/@anoopt/access-sharepoint-data-using-postman-eec5965400f2

Comment: The link is showing some text

Answer (score 1):

Log into your sharepoint site and inspect the request in your dev tools.  Copy the Cookie header and add that header to your Postman request, then your request will go through.